# Dynamically add/remove row not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

I would like to do a form that could add/remove row by clicking add/remove buttons. My problems now is that, the remove button can always just remove the last row,  instead of the row that the remove button located. When I used the array delete operator, it can delete the desired row. Yet, this method did not really delete the object in the array and probably hard for me to do the checking in the for loop. I wonder where did I do wrong?

Updated:
1. Added jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/84246/
2. Save the dropdown value to parent's state

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
     dropdown: [
         {first: "true", hideAdd: "false", result: ""}
     ]
  }
  this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this);
  this.removeRow = this.removeRow.bind(this);
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange = (key, value) => {
    let oldArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.dropdown));
    oldArray[key]['result'] = value;
    this.setState({dropdown:oldArray}, function(){
        console.log(this.state.dropdown);
        //console.log(this.state.dropdown.length)
    })
}

removeRow = (e, key) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let oldArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.dropdown));

    oldArray.slice();
    oldArray.splice(key, 1);

    for ( let i=0; i<oldArray.length; i++){

        if (i==0){
            oldArray[i]['first'] = 'true';
        }

        if (oldArray.length==1){
            oldArray[i]['hideAdd'] = 'false';
        }else{
            oldArray[i]['hideAdd'] = 'true';
            if ( i == oldArray.length-1){
                oldArray[i]['hideAdd'] = 'false';
            }   
        }

    }

    this.setState({dropdown:oldArray}, function(){
        console.log(this.state.dropdown);
        //console.log(oldArray);
        //console.log(oldArray.length);
    })

}
render() {
        return (
            <Grid.Column>
                <Grid style={comStyles().gridWidth}>
                    <Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column width={4} textAlign='left' style={comStyles().lineHeight}>Then</Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column width={12}>
                            {
                            this.state.dropdown.map((item, index) => (
                               <RulesThenDropdown default={item.result} onChange={this.onChange} add={this.addRow} remove={this.removeRow} id={index} key={index} hideAdd={item.hideAdd} first={item.first} />
                            ))
                        }
                        </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid.Row>
                </Grid>
            </Grid.Column>
        )
    }
```

And the followings are the code from the child component

```
render() {
    const Options = thenOptions;

    let extra = "";

    const removeBtn = <button onClick={(e,m)=>this.props.remove(e,this.props.id)} className="circular ui icon button"><i className="icon minus"></i></button>  
    const addBtn = <button onClick={(e,m)=>this.props.add(e,this.props.id)} className="circular ui icon button"><i className="icon plus"></i></button>

    if(this.props.first==="false"){
        if(this.props.hideAdd=="true"){
            extra = removeBtn;
        }else{
            extra = <div>{addBtn}{removeBtn}</div>;
        }
    }else if(this.props.first==="true"){
        if(this.props.hideAdd!="true"){
            extra = addBtn;
        }else{
            extra = removeBtn;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div style={comStyles().buttonsMainWrapper}>
            <Form.Dropdown 
                placeholder='Then' 
                fluid 
                selection 
                options={Options} 
                defaultValue = {this.props.result}
                onChange={(e,{ value })=>this.props.onChange(this.props.id, value)}
            />
            <div style={comStyles().buttonsGroup}>
            {
                extra
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: In the end, the problem is this line `oldArray.splice(key, 1);` ? Have you tried to `console.log` and check `oldArray` value before and after ?

Comment: Hi Firice, yes, the array seems correct

Comment: The result of `oldArray` between `splice` and `delete` are the same? What if using `delete` and clean your `oldArray` after that by `oldArray = oldArray.filter(n => n)`

Comment: Updated the post and it helps to remove the undefined one, but still removing the last row

Comment: What do you mean by 
`When I used the array delete operator, it can delete the desired row.` ?

Comment: for example, there are five rows and there is a remove button in each row respectively. If i click the third row's remove button, it is expected that the third row will be removed, but now, the last row was removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151481/discussion-between-firice-nguyen-and-hung).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're modifying the components state directly instead of updating immutable copies with this.setState().

The culprit is this line:

```
let oldArray = this.state.dropdown;
```

which doesn't copy the state but rather obtains a reference, so now both oldArray and this.state.dropdown are both pointing to the same structure in memory.

When you subsequently slice, splice and update oldArray you're breaking the React component's contract regarding state mutability (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly ).

To fix this, you'll need to deep clone `this.state.dropdown` like so:

```
let oldArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.dropdown))
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344074/501217 for details)

Comment: unfortunately the behaviour is still the same :(

Comment: You also need to assign the result of oldArray.slice() and oldArray.splice(). Unlike array.push and array.pop, they don't side-effect on the array, but rather return a new array. Since you already deep copied oldArray, you can skip the slice statement and change `oldArray.splice(...)` to `oldArray = oldArray.splice(...)`

Comment: I am sorry, i am still a bit confused. let oldArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.dropdown)); 
I firstly do this, then you mean the oldArray here is already deep copied then I can oldArray.splice(key, 1) and continue the for loop for updating some value and finally setState? coz now still the same, i am not sure if i misunderstand any of the steps

Comment: `oldArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.dropdown))` creates a deep copy of `this.state.dropdown`. When you subsequently make changes to `oldArray`, these changes are not visible in `this.state.dropdown` until you call `this.setState({dropdown: oldArray})`

Comment: I added the jsfiddle. Seems i was doing what you mentioned but not sure if the problem not because of this..

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add more to @Kim Burgaard answer, that [Immutable List](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List) is a good replacement for Array in `state`

`dropdown: List([{first: "true", hideAdd: "false", id: -1}])`